# rendering specific fields with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amf

If I have an object say

```
@user
```

and I want to render only certain fields in it say first_name and last_name(I'm using AMF)

```
render :amf => @user
```

For instance I have a property for @user which is 'dob' (date of birth) I would like to use it inside the controller business logic but I don't want to send it to the client (in this case Flex) I can defenitaly do something like this before rendering:

```
@user.dob = nil
```

But I thought there must be a better way of doing this.

how do I do that?

I know I can use :select when doing the 'find' but I need to use the other field at the server side but don't want to send them with AMF to the client side and I don't want to do a second 'find'

Thanks,

Tam

Comment: We need more information please

Comment: I added more description I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2008/09/associations-with-ruby-on-rails-flex.html) gives the details for the approach.

You have configure the **config/rubyamf_config.rb** file as follows:

```
require 'app/configuration'
module RubyAMF
  module Configuration
    ClassMappings.ignore_fields   = ['created_at','updated_at']
    ClassMappings.translate_case  = true
    ClassMappings.assume_types    = false
    ParameterMappings.scaffolding = false

    ClassMappings.register(
      :actionscript  => 'User',
      :ruby          => 'User',
      :type          => 'active_record',
      :associations  => ["employees"],
      :ignore_fields => ["dob"]
      :attributes    => ["id", "name", "location", "created_at", "updated_at"]
    )

    ClassMappings.force_active_record_ids = true
    ClassMappings.use_ruby_date_time = false
    ClassMappings.use_array_collection = true
    ClassMappings.check_for_associations = true
    ParameterMappings.always_add_to_params = true
   end
end
```